# Expected a value of type Boolean : Popup Menu

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make a popup menu and have things happen depending on which item is clicked on. The on click listener for the menu items expects a return type of type Boolean. I have given it a return type but it still all shows up in red with a message of "Expected a value of type Boolean". Could someone tell me what I have wrong here? ( I am aware I haven't made the menu clicks do anything)

```
    val menuButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.categoryImageButton)
    menuButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
         fun onClick(view: View){
             val popup = PopupMenu(this,menuButton)
             popup.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.menu)

             popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
                 **fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                     when (item.itemId) {
                         R.id.techItem -> {
                             return true
                         }
                         R.id.clothItem -> {
                             return true
                         }
                         else -> return false
                     }
                 }**
             })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have right now is somewhere half way between object expressions and a SAM constructor. Here are some options for fixing it.

You can use the full [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) syntax, which looks like this:

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object: PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.techItem -> {
                return true
            }
            R.id.clothItem -> {
                return true
            }
            else -> return false
        }
    }
})
```

You can improve the above slightly by using [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) as an expression, and returning it:

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object: PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.techItem -> {
                true
            }
            R.id.clothItem -> {
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
})
```

Or you can just use [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) to define the single function that you'd have to implement in a lambda:

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.techItem -> {
            true
        }
        R.id.clothItem -> {
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Comment: You just taught me so much. I had no idea what A SAM Conversion was or that I needed to pass in an object.